# significance of a p value in a two sided t-test

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I have a p-value of 0.00799 for a two sided t-test.
Is this value significant at the 5%, 1% or 0.1% significant level?

Comment: You set the level before looking at the data.

Answer (score 1):

$0,00799$ stand for $0,799$%. So the result is significant at $1$% level. Note that $1$% is more than *observed significance* (p-value) while $0,1$% is less.

Obviously the result is significant at 5% level also, but you have to consider the smaller significance level, but bigger that your p-value, among your alternatives. Moreover if you want a strictly binary rule (refuse or not refuse) a better idea to choose your target significance level before to see the p-value.